# How to get pageviews by url parameters?

Tags: email, url, web-analytics, usage-counters, statistics

We're sending regular newsletters to our employees about new services, documents etc which appear on our Sharepoint intranet portal.

To find out how many people came to specific page from a newsletter (NOT typing url directly or clicking link sent by IM), we can add some source parameter to newsletter link - like so: localportalurl/page/?source=email&campaign=ver4

is it possible to capture those parameters and filter using them in built-in Sharepoint page visitor statistics service?

Possibly similar, but with no answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28698/can-i-get-usage-statistics-on-pages-with-url-filtering

Comment: I would suggest to use 3rd party tool for sending newsletters from SharePoint with tracking features like it described in this review on sharepoint-community.net: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/review-of-junglemail-newsletter-and-group-email-solutio

Answer (score 1):

Anchors and GET parameters unfortunately get stripped out of the referrers, as I've learned the hard way.

What I would do would be to set up a series of web part pages with a redirection to the target content, and then link to those pages in your newsletters, so that you can collect those pages as referrer targets. It's not pretty and it'd be annoying to set it up for each new target you want to track, but it should get the job done.